# sklearn.manifold.MDS has no transform method

Tags: scikit-learn

After I make an MDS object `mds`, and fit it with `mds.fit(X)`, I thought I would be able to project new points using `mds.transform(X_new)`. I think that's the API in other manifold classes. But there is only `fit_transform`. I guess from the description that `fit_transform` does some more fitting, and I don't want to change the projection which has already been calculated!

EDIT: wait, maybe this doesn't make sense. I did some more reading. If I now understand right, the MDS algorithm is an iterative one that "just moves points around" until the stress value gets low -- and doesn't actually allow for projection.

But still, I'm a bit confused about what `fit_transform` does. The docs say "Fit the data from X, and returns the embedded coordinates". How is that different from just fitting and taking `mds.embedding_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a scikit-learn transformer, `estimator.fit_transform(X)` is [always equivalent](http://www.ecmlpkdd2013.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/lml2013_api_sklearn.pdf) to `estimator.fit(X).transform(X)`, but usually implemented more efficiently. In this case, it is indeed the same as `estimator.fit(X).embedding_`; it's there because scikit-learn classes such as `Pipeline` may call it.

It seems there's no `transform` method on any of the manifold learners, perhaps by mistake; I just opened an [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2887) about this.

Comment: Thanks larsmans. I think I read your reply before your edit. I'll join in on Github.

Answer (score 2):

sklearn MDS, SpectralEnbedding, and TSNE cannot be used for feature reduction for classification. They do not have a stand-alone transform() method like KernelPCA or LocallyLinearEmbedding. Without a transform() method, there is no way to transform and score new data.

MDS and TSNE are used for feature set analysis only. Typical examples are for visualization, but their use in feature analysis goes beyond just visualization.

Use PCA for linearly separable feature sets and a non-linear transformer like LLE for non-linearly separable feature sets.